# How can I disable shrinking/resiziing images in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following set-up

- Bootstrap 2.2.1
- HTML loaded in a layer via AJAX
- layer is 600 px width on a desktop monitor

I want to show small images (32x32 pixel):

```
<img src="/img/icon_line.png" class="img-polaroid" width="32" height="32" />
```

What happens is that they got shrinked to tiny size through the following css rule in bootstrap.css:

```
img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

How can I avoid this and show the icons  in full size in my layer?

**Update:** 
I figured out that this occurs when the images are in a table and the table rows have much text inside and everything is in a layer.

Here is a simplified example of my use case:

- Long text, broken: http://www.another-showroom.com/bootstrap/broken.html
- Short  text, ok: http://www.another-showroom.com/bootstrap/ok.html
- Example as zip file: http://www.another-showroom.com/bootstrap/bsbug.zip

**Fixed version:**

- http://www.another-showroom.com/bootstrap/fixed.html

Comment: Are you sure no other rules are coming in to play here? I've set up an example with Bootstrap loaded showing that setting dimensions in either the markup or CSS produces the expected result. http://jsfiddle.net/rCNRf/

Comment: I added some links to example code online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for table cell with image next code:

```
<td class="span1">
     <img src="img/icon_line.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Ligne">
</td>
```

Comment: thanx a lot. I realized now that images in Bootstrap adapt to the parent's width which is a td in this case.